# php substr() for utf-8 characters without whitespace

Tags: php, substring, substr

```
  <?php
  $utf8string = "سلامجهان";
    echo substr($utf8string,0,5);
?>
    //output سل�
```

How to fix substr() for utf-8 in php?

Comment: You're looking for [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr), as can be seen [here](http://3v4l.org/78T65).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        $utf8string = "سلامجهان";
        echo mb_substr($utf8string,0,5,'UTF-8');
        //output سلامج
?>
```

Use [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/mb_substr) and set utf-8 for it!

```
//sample  mb_substr($YourString,first char,length of output char,charset name);
```

Comment: The third parameter is for length, not end position.